# Join string in a specific row on python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I’m attempting to join a string in a specific row in the python dataframe but it does not work.
The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'TR':np.arange(1, 6).repeat(5), 'A': np.random.randint(1, 100,25), 'B':  np.random.randint(50, 100,25), 'C':  np.random.randint(50, 1000,25), 'D':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25) })

df.loc[df.TR == 1, 'TR'] = 'TA' 
df.loc[df.TR == 2, 'TR'] = 'TB' 
df.loc[df.TR == 3, 'TR'] = 'TC' 
df.loc[df.TR == 4, 'TR'] = 'TD'
df.loc[df.TR == 5, 'TR'] = 'TE'

table = df.groupby('TR').mean().round(decimals=1)

T_letter = [ '','A', 'A', 'A',]
T_letter2 = [ 'A','B', 'C', 'A',]
table.loc['TB'].astype(str) +T_letter
table.loc['TD'].astype(str) +T_letter2
```

It should be like this:

```
     A     B      C     D
TR                         
TA  54.0  68.6  795.8  49.8
TB  61.4  67.8A 524.8A 52.8A
TC  54.0  73.6  556.6  46.6
TD  35.6A 69.2B 207.2C 46.4A
TE  44.4  85.0  639.8  73.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close! TLDR - Here is your answer:

```
table.loc['TB'] = table.loc['TB'].astype(str) +T_letter
table.loc['TD'] = table.loc['TD'].astype(str) +T_letter2
```

Explanation:

".loc" creates a Pandas Series:

```
>> type(table.loc['TB'])

pandas.core.series.Series
```

Performing any functions/concatenation on this will only perform the function on the series itself. To save it you would have to set it equal to a variable.

```
>> not_my_dataframe = table.loc['TB'].astype(str) +T_letter2

>> type(not_my_dataframe)

pandas.core.series.Series

>> print(not_my_dataframe)
A     39.8A
B     79.6B
C    519.8C
D     53.6A
Name: TB, dtype: object
```

You need to assign it back to the series you pulled it from in the original Dataframe

```
table.loc['TB'] = table.loc['TB'].astype(str) +T_letter
table.loc['TD'] = table.loc['TD'].astype(str) +T_letter2
>> print(table)
        A      B       C      D
TR                             
TA     54   68.6   795.8   49.8
TB   61.4  67.8A  524.8A  52.8A
TC     54   73.6   556.6   46.6
TD  35.6A  69.2B  207.2C  46.4A
TE   44.4     85   639.8   73.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it by iterrows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'TR':np.arange(1, 6).repeat(5), 'A': np.random.randint(1, 100,25), 'B':  np.random.randint(50, 100,25), 'C':  np.random.randint(50, 1000,25), 'D':  np.random.randint(5, 100,25) })

df.loc[df.TR == 1, 'TR'] = 'TA'
df.loc[df.TR == 2, 'TR'] = 'TB'
df.loc[df.TR == 3, 'TR'] = 'TC'
df.loc[df.TR == 4, 'TR'] = 'TD'
df.loc[df.TR == 5, 'TR'] = 'TE'

table = df.groupby('TR').mean().round(decimals=1)

T_letter = [ '','A', 'A', 'A',]
T_letter2 = [ 'A','B', 'C', 'A',]
table = table.astype(object) #convert to object type to allow string insertion

for idx, row in table.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if idx == "TB":
            row[i] = str(row[i]) + T_letter[i]
        elif idx == "TD":
            row[i] = str(row[i]) + T_letter2[i]

print(table)

#Output:
        A      B       C      D
TR                             
TA     54   68.6   795.8   49.8
TB   61.4  67.8A  524.8A  52.8A
TC     54   73.6   556.6   46.6
TD  35.6A  69.2B  207.2C  46.4A
TE   44.4     85   639.8   73.8
```